# How to create a object with user persistent settings?

Tags: python, class, module, global-variables, settings

I'm trying to create a module called "settings.py" to store user preferences. I don't want to use any library to store those preferences because I want to access it from a object after load. Follow a example what I want:

```
-----> module 'settings.py'

#global object that returns stored settings
GLOBAL_SETTINGS = None


#class that create the object 
class UserSettings:
    def __init__(self, name, age, team):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.team = team

#method to save settings in a file
def save_settings():
        global GLOBAL_SETTINGS
        with open('userSettings.config', 'w') as data:
            data.write(json.dumps(vars(GLOBAL_SETTINGS.__dict__), indent=4))
    
#method to load settings from a file
def load_settings():
        global GLOBAL_SETTINGS
        jsonItem = open('userSettings.config', 'r', encoding='UTF-8').read()
        GLOBAL_SETTINGS = UserSettings(**jsonItem)
```

And when I call 'GLOBAL_SETTINGS', I access this stored informations, like this:

```
-----> module 'main.py'

def load_settings():
    settings.load_settings()
    print (f'The team of {settings.GLOBAL_SETTINGS.name} is {settings.GLOBAL_SETTINGS.team}!')

load_settings()
```

I want a code like this because my application has many, many user preferences, and I want to load all attribute names just using "ctrl+space" in PyCharm. If I load the settings by other way, I can call the attributes only using "['nameOfAttribute']".

Comment: Ok - is your code working? If not where is it blocking? Is the userSettings.config file being created? Does it contain the right information? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Yes, it works, but not the way I want. The problem is that I can't load the "GLOBAL_SETTINGS." attributes using "ctrl+space" because it isn't recognized as a "UserSettings" object. I need to load with ctrl+space because the original module has many attributes, and complex names. I tried to declare it as a "UserSettings" object, but I can't do it. (GLOBAL_SETTINGS: settings.UserSettings() doesn't work for it)